# I get error in installing the npx create- react- app I have also tried the npm globally but both not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am installing the React app through `npx create-react-app my-app` but getting error which are as follow:

```
PS C:\Users\NAEEM UR REHMAN\Desktop\react_app> npx create-react-app my-app

npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL

npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\NAEEM UR REHMAN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-09T10_01_07_251Z-debug-0.log
```

First when I run the command so it was running but after some time they stop and giving error of something unstable network connectivity and proxy setting then I clear the cache after that when I run the command it is giving the error also when I try to install it globally they also give error which is below:

```
PS C:\Users\NAEEM UR REHMAN\Desktop\react_test> npm install -g create-react-app -timeout=6000000
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_proxy_server
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\NAEEM UR REHMAN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-09T17_02_58_707Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Seems like you might have configured a proxy literally named `your_proxy_server`, which may not actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the below command.

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: Note that `create-react-app` (CRA) is deprecated and will have no future releases other than bug fixes (if any).  You are encouraged to move to a newer development system such as Vite.